# Is it possible to reload a parent php file WITHOUT javascript?[WORKS !]

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to reload a parent php file WITHOUT javascript ?I dont wanna use Javascript because if the client has disabled Javascript .

So I have a object and there should be a button to change the background color of the main page

`parent.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
    <?php 
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['backgroundcolor'] = '#fcba03';
    ?>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:<?php echo $_SESSION['backgroundcolor'];?>">
    <object data="changebackground.php" width="500" height="200">
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

`changebackground.php`:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="change bgcolor" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
$var = "#ff0000";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $_SESSION['backgroundcolor'] = $var;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, but it involves a round trip to the server, because PHP only runs in the server, not in the browser

Comment: _NOTE_ If you dont have any code to go in an ELSE, then you dont need to code an empty ELSE

Comment: The likelihood of someone having JavaScript disabled in the current world is very, very small, to the point that I wouldn't concern yourself with it. For better or worse, large chunks of the internet aren't usable without it. But, if this is a big concern, you can require JS for your application and have a `<noscript>` block that tells people at the start that they need to have JS enabled to use your site.

Comment: Why not use a `<form>` for this?

Comment: @NicoHaase How could I use <form>

Comment: what if they have cookies disabled too, your session won't work? Ok, rather then <object>'ing your form client side, simply <?php include 'changebackground.php' ?> on the parent.. btw session_start won't work there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your literal question, the only solution I can think is to use the `target` element in either a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) or a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target) (`_top` should work but `_parent` is probably more accurate):

> - `_self`: the current browsing context. (Default)
> - `_blank`: usually a new tab, but users can configure browsers to open a new window instead.
> - `_parent`: the parent browsing context of the current one. If no parent, behaves as _self.
> - `_top`: the topmost browsing context (the "highest" context that’s an ancestor of the current one). If no ancestors, behaves as _self.

How to fit this with your current logic is a different subject. The main issue is that these elements require a manual user intervention: user has to click to trigger the action since we don't want JavaScript to do it for him. Thus you need to merge the change colour form with the reload parent frame feature. The most obvious way is to perform the colour changing action at `parent.php`.

Comment: Thanks it worked I marked your answer as right and my question as solved 
I made a own anser with the modified script

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Álvaro González ,
I now solved the problem this is my Current script

> Parent.php

```
<!doctype html>
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Change Backgroundcolor with pure PHP</title>
<?php 
          
      if(empty($_SESSION['backgroundcolor'])){
        $_SESSION['backgroundcolor']='#fcba03';
      }else{
      }
    ?>
 </head>
  <body style="background-color:<?php echo $_SESSION['backgroundcolor']; ?>;" >
  <?php 
    

    echo $_SESSION['backgroundcolor'];
    echo '<object data="changebackground.php" width="500" height="200">';
    
  ?>
    
          
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

> changebackground.php

```html
<form action="" method="post" target="_parent">
<input type="submit" value="change bgcolor" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
  session_start();  
  $var= "#ff0000";
if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $_SESSION['backgroundcolor']=$var;
    header("Refresh:0; url=parent.php");
};

?>
```